# Google Cloud cancel replacing instances in group

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

How is it possible to cancel replacing instances in instance group without website going offline? We have a managed instance group of compute engine instances, we start replace operation with maximum unavailable instances set to 0, if new instance for some reason doesn't become healthy there is an option to remove instance. However it removes all instances making website to go down until a new instance is created. Is it supposed to happen?

Comment: Do you have a technical recipe of the environment you created?  Either a set of gcloud commands for scripting or a Deployment Manager input?

Comment: What's your Minimum number of instances  ? 
Is it possible all of your instances are in unhealthy condition ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be expected behavior. Please have a look at [rolling update](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/updating-managed-instance-groups) in order to update your instance.  Striving for 0 downtime could be achievable. To make your servers more responsive and less disruptive, you may consider the following two strategies:

[Max surge](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/updating-managed-instance-groups?hl=en_US&_ga=2.158638522.-1028673997.1532983356&_gac=1.174834966.1533939808.EAIaIQobChMI5riNg8Pj3AIVAtlkCh1ACgUuEAAYASAAEgLIK_D_BwE#max_surge). This will create instances above the target size in order to speed up the update process.

[Opportunistic update](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/updating-managed-instance-groups?hl=en_US&_ga=2.158638522.-1028673997.1532983356&_gac=1.174834966.1533939808.EAIaIQobChMI5riNg8Pj3AIVAtlkCh1ACgUuEAAYASAAEgLIK_D_BwE#starting_an_opportunistic_or_proactive_update).  “An opportunistic update is only applied when new instances are created by the managed instance group”